# Inherit react components with mobx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a component which inherits from a abstract class and uses mobx decorators like this:

```
@inject("matrixStore")
@observer
export default class DayRow<T extends IAbstractRowProps = IAbstractRowProps> extends AbstractRow<T> {
     // ...
}
```

The render function itself lives in the AbstractRow component.

I inherit from DayRow with another component:

```
@inject("matrixStore")
@observer
export default class DayFinderRow extends DayRow<IDayFinderRowProps> {
}
```

But when I try to render `DayFinderRow` there is a warning from mobx:
`Mobx observer: You are trying to use 'observer' on a component that already has 'inject'. Please apply 'observer' before applying 'inject'`. And wenn I debug the rendered component it says `inject-DayRow-with-matrixStore#0.render()` instead of the anticipated `DayFinderRow#0.render()`

When I remove the decorators from `DayFinderRow`, the warning is gone, but instead of a `DayFinderRow` component a `DayRow` gets rendered.

I need the decorators on both components, since I render both, but want to derive DayFinderRow from the DayRow, because I only need to change the behaviour of one function.

Is this possible with mobx?

Comment: Have you tried just following the advice of the error message and switching the order of the `@inject()` and `@observer` decorators on each component declaration?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change the error message, but breaks the application, since it also creates a `inject-DayRow-with-matrixStore#0.render()` component for my `DayRow` components. Seems like there is something broken with the decorators when inheriting.

Comment: Funny enough: When I inherit DayFinderRow from AbstractRow, it works perfectly. So there seems to be an issue when inheriting from components, that are already injecting and/or observing stuff.

Comment: may its because DayRow injects matrixStore... ur extending it with DayFinderRow which also injects matrixStore... ->  did u thought about using a container and injects the store to it instead of injecting to each component? [nice article about react container](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook says that inheritance is not suitable. Here is their explanation and recommendations.

There is no good reason for me to use React Component as blueprint.
The function composition makes more sense to me.

Here is what face book says about that :

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html